# A permutation of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ disturbing distances is a group homomorphism?

Tags: permutations, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

Originating from a table permutation problem (which I first thought was easy...) is my following question, about some permutations of cyclic groups:

Let $n\ge 1$ be an integer and identify the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with the set $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ through the "obvious" bijection $\phi$, whose inverse is just given by
$$\{0,1,...,n-1\}\ni i\longmapsto \bar{i}\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$

Now **define a distance** in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ by setting
$$d(x,y)=\min(\phi(x-y),\phi(y-x))\in\{0,1,...,n-1\},$$
for all $(x,y)\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$.

In more concrete terms, just put clockwise the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ on the vertices of a regular $n$-gone (or sit $n$ guests around a circular table). The distance between two elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is just the usual graph distance between the associated vertices.

**My question is:**
Assume $\sigma$ is a *disturbing* permutation of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., a permutation such that:

- $\sigma(0)=0$,
- For all $(x,y)\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$, $d(\sigma(x),\sigma(y))\neq d(x,y)$,

*(in the table analogy, $\sigma$ is just a permutation of the guests such that the distance between any two guests before and after the permutation is different)*

Then is it true that $\sigma$ is (i.e. has to be) a group automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Do you mean "is it *possibly* a group homomorphism," or "does it *have* to be one?"

Comment: Well I am not 100% sure of it, but I feel like $\sigma$ has to be a group homomorphism. That is in fact the only way I could construct some of these, and this means $n$ is not even (nor a multiple of $3$)

Comment: Could you say why $n$ cannot be even or a multiple of 3, if it isn't too involved? [I tried unsuccessfully $n=9$]

Comment: Sure. We check immediately (via the definition, or through the $n$-gone analogy) that $d(x,y)=d(x’,y’)$ iff. $x-y=x’-y’$ or $x-y=y’-x’$. If $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ then it’s given by $\sigma(x)=a.x$ for some $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, then $d(x,y)=d(x’,y’)$ implies $d(\sigma(x),\sigma(y))=d(\sigma(x’),\sigma(y’))$.
In other words, $\sigma$ acts homogenously on distances by permuting pairs at a given distance with pairs at (a different) given distance.

Comment: If $n=2k$ is even, one has exactly $n$ pairs at distance $1$, $n$ pairs at distance $2$, …, $n$ pairs at distance $k-1$, and just $k$ pairs at distance $k$. Thus, any automorphism $\sigma$ must send pairs at distance $k$ to pairs at distance $k$: contradiction with what we want.

Comment: If $n$ is a multiple of $3$ and $\sigma:x\mapsto a.x$ with $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. Then either $a+1$ or $a-1$ is a multiple of $3$. Assume it’s $a+1$: then one can find $x\neq y$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $(a+1)(x-y)=0$, i.e. $a(x-y)=-(x-y)$, therefore $d(\sigma(x),\sigma(y))=d(x,y)$.Same argument if $a-1$ is multiple of $3$.

Comment: Yoel-- Does this show there cannot be any map at all that works if $n$ is a multiple of $3,$ or only that homomorphisms don't lead to examples? [sorry, didn't know how to make an umlaut]

Comment: You're right, I only showed that (auto)morphisms don't work if $n$ is divisible by 2 or 3. Now I want to know whether there can be "disturbing" permutations that are not homomorphisms, which I'm yet to find an example of.

Comment: Just notice that I would only need to show that any *disturbing* permutation acts homogeneously on distances, i.e., induces bijections between "distance cosets" of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$ (i.e. sets of the form $\{(x,y)\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2; d(x,y)=d\}$) . This would at least be enough for the original table problem I was given (i.e., there are no disturbing permutations if $n$ is even).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer I found somewhere (reformulated a little bit) to a weaker problem, which was my original one:

*"An even number of guests are sitting around a circular table. They all stand up and sit again, but in a different order. Show that there are at least two people which are sitting at the same distance (=minimal number of guests between them) as before"*

My claim about any "disturbing permutation" being a group automorphism is not proved and is perhaps (trivially) wrong.

Set $n=2m$ and let $f:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ be a permutation. There are two cases:

1- For all $d\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $f_d:=f+d$ has a fixed point, i.e. for all $d$ one has some $i_d\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(i_d)+d=i_d$.
Thus one has
$$\sum_{d\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}i_d=\sum_{d\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}(f(i_d)+d)
=\sum_{d\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}f(i_d)+\sum_{d\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}d$$
But the $i_d$'s have to be pairwise distinct by construction, so $d\mapsto i_d$ and $d\mapsto f(i_d)$ are bijections of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, therefore $\sum_{d\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}d$ has to be $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.
But $\sum_{d\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}d=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=m(2m-1)\equiv -m\neq 0$ $\mod n$, which gives a contradiction.

2- There is some $d\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f_d$ has no fixed point. The problem is translation-invariant (as we are only dealing with distances) so we may still assume $d=0$ (up to replacing $f$ by $f_d$), i.e. $f$ has no fixed point.
Let $f':=f-id$. As $f'(i)\neq 0$, $\forall i\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ then $f$ is not surjective, thus not injective i.e., there exists $i\neq j$ such that $f'(i)=f'(j)$, i.e.,
$f(i)-f(j)=-(i-j)$ which means $d(f(i),f(j))=d(i,j)$.